# Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment'

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

```
compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:1.0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0
```

When I add the above fragment to my project and run the Android gradle build task for the project, the fragment is not imported or built

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please would you add more detail, for example, are you getting an error message? Then you will get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

and remove

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0
```